# An issue with nested divs

Tags: css, nested

I'm sure there's a simple solution to this, but I've been beating my head up against it for an hour or two and not making much progress.

Basically, I've got a wrapper div (testwrap_outer) containing a secondary wrapper div (testwrap_inner) that holds together an image thumbnail div (test1), and a caption div (test2).

I need the caption div (test2) to scale height according to its content, the secondary wrapper (testwrap_inner) to contain that div and float next to any other secondary wrapper divs, and the main wrapper (testwrap_outer) to contain all of them.

I apologize for doing such a poor job explaining, so I've provided a picture to illustrate what I mean [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQr1l.jpg). Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3hz8dss).

**HTML**

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi congue mi at aliquet blandit. Praesent tristique, dui sit amet iaculis mollis, nunc elit semper nisi, vitae finibus nulla dui in enim. In lacinia aliquam tempus. Nunc sollicitudin ac massa non porttitor. Maecenas quam urna, semper ut mauris id, lacinia consequat libero. Vivamus neque diam, vestibulum a est eget, aliquam tempus magna. Morbi sed tellus lobortis, condimentum mi id, finibus felis.</p>

<div class=testwrap_outer>
    <div class=testwrap_inner>
        <!-- THUMBNAIL IMAGE -->
        <div class=test1>
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/5KObDyq.jpg">
        </div>
        <!-- THUMBNAIL CAPTION -->
        <div class=test2><b>TEST2</b>
            <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi congue mi at aliquet blandit. Praesent tristique, dui sit amet iaculis mollis, nunc elit semper nisi, vitae finibus nulla dui in enim.</div>
    </div>
    <div class=testwrap_inner>
        <!-- THUMBNAIL IMAGE -->
        <div class=test1>
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/5KObDyq.jpg">
        </div>
        <!-- THUMBNAIL CAPTION -->
        <div class=test2><b>TEST2</b>
            <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi congue mi at aliquet blandit. Praesent tristique, dui sit amet iaculis mollis, nunc elit semper nisi, vitae finibus nulla dui in enim.</div>
    </div>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi congue mi at aliquet blandit. Praesent tristique, dui sit amet iaculis mollis, nunc elit semper nisi, vitae finibus nulla dui in enim. In lacinia aliquam tempus. Nunc sollicitudin ac massa non porttitor. Maecenas quam urna, semper ut mauris id, lacinia consequat libero. Vivamus neque diam, vestibulum a est eget, aliquam tempus magna. Morbi sed tellus lobortis, condimentum mi id, finibus felis.</p>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background: #cccccc;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    min-width: 900px;
}
.testwrap_outer {
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
}
.testwrap_inner {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 4px;
    width: 296px;
}
.test1 {
    border: 1px solid purple;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    opacity: 1.0;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    overflow: hidden
}
.test1 img {
    height: 100%;
}
.test1 img:hover {
    opacity: 0.6;
}
.test2 {
    border: 0px solid green;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    text-align: justify;
    text-justify: inter-word;
    padding: 6px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: QUESTION RESOLVED:  Should anyone else facing this problem stumble onto this question, Aru's answer seems to me to be the most intuitive solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add inside `testwrap_outer` an empty `div` with `clear:both` style. This will tidy up the layout and make the outer `div` behave as a container supposed to be behave.
Updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/a3hz8dss/1/

Answer (score 0):

just include `overflow:hidden` in your class `testwrap_outer`, also there is no need of `position:relative` in your code!!

**CSS:**

```
.testwrap_outer{
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a3hz8dss/2/)

Comment: Thanks very much both for providing a solution and pointing out a mistake.  position: relative ended up there as a direct result of novice inexperience telling me to throw everything I can think of at the problem.